# Call not call a function inside a FlatList in react native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-flatlist

I am developing an App using react native. I want to pass a parameter to a function in my flatlist for a specific record. But, the flat list ignore this line of code:
`onPress={ () => {console.log("TEST1"); this.onPressTopUp()} } />`

Here is my code:

```
<FlatList
ItemSeparatorComponent={ () => <View style={ styles.rowSep } /> }
horizontal={false}
data={this.state.result}

renderItem={
     ({item}) => (
          <View style={styles.containerrow}>
          <View style={styles.viewPark}>

          <Text style={styles.itemBold}> {I18n.t('Data_e_ora_inizio')}:
          <Text style={styles.itemNormal}>{item.start}</Text></Text>             
          <Text style={styles.itemBold}> {I18n.t('Data_e_ora_termine')}: 
          <Text style={styles.itemNormal}>{item.end}</Text></Text>
          <Text style={styles.itemBold}> {I18n.t('Energia')}: <Text style={styles.itemNormal}>{item.energy_delivered}</Text></Text>
          <Text style={styles.itemBold}> {I18n.t('Colonna')}: <Text style={styles.itemNormal}>{item.column_id}</Text></Text>
          <Text style={styles.itemBold}> {I18n.t('Costo_della_ricarica')}: 
          <Text style={styles.itemNormal}>€ {item.amount}</Text></Text>
          <Text style={styles.itemBold}> {I18n.t('Aggiornamento_del')}:     
          <Text style={styles.itemNormal}>{item.last_update}</Text></Text>
                                         </View>

        <View style={styles.rowCenter}>
          <Button label={I18n.t('Via_questa_ricarica')} color={defStyleValues.RechargeElectricCar} onPress={ () => {console.log("TEST1"); this.onPressTopUp()} } />
               </View>
            </View>
          )
        }
    keyExtractor={item => item.id}
 />
```

Also here is my function:

```
onPressTopUp(columnID){
        console.log("TEST2, ", columnID);
}
```

In other words, My problem is that I need to pass columnID of each specific row to the `onPressTopUp(columnID)` function in the FlatList. I checked the console log, even it dose't show both TEST1 and TEST2. Can you help me to do that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use Arrow Function , it will take care of binding.

your function is :-

```
onPressTopUp(columnID){
        console.log("TEST2, ", columnID);
}
```

**Replace with Arrow Function :-**  and it will work for you.

```
onPressTopUp = (columnID) => {
     console.log("Test, ", columnID);
}
```

**and change your label Property with title inside your Button**

You can use Button like this below :-

```
import { Button } from 'react-native';
...

<Button
  onPress={onPressLearnMore}
  title="Learn More"
  color="#841584"
  accessibilityLabel="Learn more about this purple button"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. it worked. Voted up and mark as an answer.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is you had not `bind` the `onPressToUp` function, try this:

```
onPressTopUp = (columnID) => {
     console.log("Test, ", columnID);
```

}

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I should both bind and use the code above?

Comment: the function I wrote above has already `bind`. But you have to send `columnID` when you call the `onPressTopUp` function in `Button`

Comment: I voted up, since it helped me for a part. :) Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Is Button component imported from React Native? Because react native Button component doesn't have label property. 
Did you try call function with column id like this this.onPressTopUp(15).
Hope this help.